# Bind 2 table together (one to many relationship)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I am pretty new to c#, EF Code First and all that, so my question might be an easy one.

I am trying to create a very simple login. Each user must have a type (admin or client). How can I bind the usertype to my user table without generating a new type each time I insert a new user in the DB?
Here are my code first class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public UserType TypeId { get; set; }
}

public class UserType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public enum TypeEnum
{
    Admin,
    Client
}
```

When I launch the app, I want to be able to create 2 tables:

- Users which is empty
- UserTypes which must contain 2 types (Admin and Client).

Then, everytime I register a new user, so everytime I add a user to the Users table, I want to be able to use the UserTypes table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I launch the app, I want to be able to create 2 tables...

Not sure if I understand this correctly but you can *seed* initial data into the database with EF Code-First. An example how to do that is here:

[Entity Framework Inserting Initial Data On Rebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616493/entity-framework-inserting-initial-data-on-rebuild/7616723#7616723)

If you really want to recreate the tables with every launch of your application you can use the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<T>` initializer as mentioned in the example.

> Then, everytime I register a new user, so everytime I add a user to
>   the Users table, I want to be able to use the UserTypes table.

For this you would load the existing `UserType` you want to assign from the database so that it is attached to the context and then create the new user:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var userType = context.UserTypes
        .Single(u => u.Type == TypeEnum.Admin.ToString());
    var newUser = new User { TypeId = userType, Username = ... etc. };

    context.Users.Add(newUser);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Attaching to the context - by either loading from the database or calling `Attach` explicitely - makes sure that the `UserType` is not duplicated, i.e. no INSERT command will be sent to the database for the `UserType`.

Answer (score 2):

With new version of EF (currently beyond the offical 4.1 version: [Entity Framework June 2011 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/29/enumeration-support-in-entity-framework.aspx)) you can also do that:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public UserType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum UserType
{
    Admin = 1,
    Client = 2,
}
```

The data will be saved as integer in your database but within your application you can use your enum like this:

```
    var newUser = new User { Type = UserType.Admin, Username = ... };

    context.Users.Add(newUser);

    context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Good idea! I took the freedom to add to your question what "new version" exactly means.