# Insert initial values after EF migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-migration

I have an MVC web application with code-first Entity Framework. We install this application in various computers as a local application. I made a migration to upgrade the database (in this case I added a new table), and after running the migration on upgrade, I want to insert initial data to the database so the users will be able to add/edit/delete them but I don't want the table to be empty at the first time.

Is there a way to do it automatically on upgrade without running a SQL script manually?

Comment: Search for seeding database in EF, this might help you

Comment: Seed is not only for the first time the database is created? In need only after a specific migration

Comment: And also I don't want that my code will run more than once, if I add more migration in the future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migration class has `up` method,you can override it and insert/update records using `SQL` :

```
public override void Up() {
AddColumn("dbo.Posts", "Abstract", c => c.String());
Sql("UPDATE dbo.Posts SET Abstract = LEFT(Content, 100) WHERE Abstract IS NULL");
}
```

([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx))

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I used a lot of Sql("INSERT [dbo].....") and it did it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You essentially write a class to conditionally check and insert values, and then you link this class to your entity framework database initialiser. It runs each time there is a migration to be performed, but I think you can change exactly when it runs (e.g. Application startup).

This link will give you the rough idea:
[Entity Framework Inserting Initial Data On Rebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616493/entity-framework-inserting-initial-data-on-rebuild)

I have an exact code sample on my PC but I won't be on it until tomorrow. If this link doesn't quite do what you want, I can send you some code tomorrow which definitely will.